# Cordova Network Information Plugin - Case not handled

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have used cordova network interface plugin and have registered for offline and online event listeners.

When Using cellular or Wi-Fi network, any change in state of network (on-off or off-on) triggers an event in the event listener. But when connected to a Wi-Fi or mobile hotspot and if the internet of the Wi-Fi or mobile hotspot changes, no event is triggered in the event listener.

Is there a way to to be notified on case there is no internet connectivity on the Wi-Fi or mobile hotspot?

Note: I have tried the above on Android phones.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the network type using [cordova-plugin-network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) in your on-off event.

Comment: I have already specified in the question that I do not get any on/off event in case there is no internet connectivity in the connected Wi-Fi or Hotspot.

Comment: In this case try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events). It worked for me on android some days ago.

Comment: If you're referring to online and offline event listeners, then I've already done that. It's also mentioned in the question.